# data-cfasync to validate (W3C)

Tags: javascript, xhtml, w3c-validation

I am trying to validate my document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional (W3C).

I have the following error:

> there is no attribute "data-cfasync"

which corresponds to this line:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type='text/javascript'>/*<![CDATA[*/window.olark||(function(c){var f=window,d=document,l=f.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:",z=c.name,r="load";var nt=function(){
```

Please see the source code:

```
<!-- begin olark code -->
<script data-cfasync="false" type='text/javascript'>/*<![CDATA[*/window.olark||(function(c){var f=window,d=document,l=f.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:",z=c.name,r="load";var nt=function(){..................
]]>*/</script><noscript><a href="https://www.olark.com.....
<!-- end olark code -->
```

Please help me to pass validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t have a `data-cfasync` attribute in XHTML 1.0.

The [custom `data-*` attributes are defined for HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) (for both syntaxes, HTML and XHTML).

So either switch to XHTML5, or use a different attribute ([e.g., `class`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/64961/17633)).